# QNX OS - CPP Application: Error: Malloc Check Failed crash

Tags: c++, delete-operator, qnx-neutrino

I'm using QNX OS and my application is in C++. Am getting an error message as shown below and my program is crashing.

```
Malloc Check Failed: :/builds/workspace/QOS221-SDP/build_aarch64/lib/c/alloc/dlist.c:1057
Abort (core dumped)
```

I don't have dlist.c source code to check. The same application I have it in Windows and its working perfectly. Due to security reasons I'm not able to share the code.

I'm not double freeing the memory or NULL pointer.
I've printed the ptr addresses the no.of bytes allocated during allocMemory. and when freeing also before deleting I've checked whether its not NULL and when I printed the ptr address and no.of.bytes allocated, it is showing the same.

```
After allocating:
newNumBytes:: ptr==>13eb4040::numBytes==>67584

Before deallocate:
deleteNumBytes:: ptr==>13eb4040::numBytes==>67584

deleteNumBytes(
    T&            ptr,
    const int32_t numBytes  
)
{
    // Here T is the pointer and and not the pointed type
    //
    static_assert(sizeof(T)   == sizeof(void*),"error");
    static_assert(sizeof(ptr) == sizeof(void*),"error");
    if (numBytes > 0)
    {
            if(ptr != NULL)
            {
                delete[] ptr;
                ptr = NULL;
            }        
    }
}
```

Everytime it is crashing on the same variable but that variable seems to be having valid memory address. Core dump is not useful. I don't have any tool like valgrind.

1. Any hint on why its crashing?
2. Is there anyway I could get dlist.c source code from QNX SDP?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/vocho/openqnx/blob/master/trunk/lib/c/alloc/dlist.c#L1057

Comment: One can write ones own malloc/free with counts, with a long 0xa5a5a5a5L before and after, checked on free and there zeroed first. Also `if (numBytes > 0)` disregards too much, maybe drop that requirement.

Comment: How is `ptr` allocated?  In particular, did you use `new[]` (as opposed to just `new`)?

Comment: yes. Used new[] operator to allocate ptr.

Comment: I did go through the dlist.c from openqnx. Its not latest update I think. And also in that source code there is no assert()/panic with "malloc check failed"